# Protractor 5.1.1 selenium-webdriver version inconsitency

Tags: selenium, protractor

I've recently upgraded to Protractor 5.1.1 and am facing some issues when setting cookies via browser.manage().addCookie()

The API has changed between versions 2 and 3 of Selenium-webdriver to expect an object rather than the previous 2..6 arguments. When I make the changes to my code to use the object, the typescript compiler complains saying that it expects 2..6 arguments.

old api:

```
browser.manage().addCookie('cookieName',  'cookieVal');
```

new api:

```
browser.manage().addCookie({name:'cookieName', value: 'cookieVal'});
```

I think this is because the @types/selenium-webdriver in the package.json of protractor v5.1.1 is pointing at version 2.53.39.  The version of the actual selenium-webdriver the same package.json is referencing is 3.0.1.

Should this be the same value?  Is anyone else experiencing problems with this?

Comment: Protractor also has a dependency on webdriver-js-extender, which references older versions of @types/selenium-webdriver and selenium-webdriver in its package.json.  Is there any way of overriding these to force my project to use the versions I have specified in my projects package.json?

Answer (score 2):

Yup, this is happening because the type definitions was not written at the time.

## workaround

Here is the workaround for now:

```
(browser.manage() as any).addCookie({name:'cookieName', value: 'cookieVal'});
```

We are setting browser.manage returned options object to `any`. Then we can give it the `addCookie` method.

OR

## upgrade definitions

you could upgrade your @types/selenium-webdriver type definitions to version 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem! I do know that the @types/selenium-driver is now updated to version 3.0.0.

I haven't had luck with this, but you could try installing it directly (i.e. *npm install --save-dev @types/selenium-webdriver*) and adding it to your list of types in your tsconfig.json file (i.e. **types: [ "selenium-webdriver"** ].

Comment: I found by right-clicking on the addCookie function in Visual Studio Code and selecting **Go to Type Definition**, I'm taken to the @types/selenium-webdriver (v2) in the node_modules for protractor and not the version (version 3) I installed in the root node_modules/@types folder.

Comment: I get the same.  Intellij is using the @types/selenium-webdriver from protractor rather than the one defined in my tsconfig.json as you have suggested.  the only way I can get it to use the correct one is to rename/remove the selenium-webdriver from the protractor and webdriver-js-extender node_modules directory and then it works as it uses my installed version, but this obviously breaks the build.